# Config to make only pcap receive packet

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, pcap

I am trying to use pcap to modify the packet before sending it out. For example, I have a server (running Ubuntu) listening on port 8000. Before it sends out SYN-ACK for incoming SYN packet, I am trying to modify the SYN-ACK using pcap.

So far, I can receive the SYN-ACK generated by the OS in pcap, modify and send it out. But there are two packets sent out: (1) original SYN-ACK packet generated by OS, (2) pcap modified packet.

I know this is not surprising as OS sends a copy of the packet to pcap for processing, and original packet is sent out separately.

When I dropped the outgoing SYN-ACK packet (generated by OS) using iptables, I could not even receive the SYN-ACK in the pcap.

My question is: Is it possible to drop the original SYN-ACK packet and only send out the pcap modified packet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your target IP is 8.8.8.8

On your origin host, set up a route like this:

```
route 8.8.8.8 mask 255.255.255.255 gateway 192.168.1.254
```

Where the gateway IP address is on the local network and doesn't exist (this isn't the actual command, use the syntax dependent on the route tool you use).

Then add an arp entry:

```
arp -s 192.168.1.254 11:22:33:44:55:66
```

Now any packets from the host destined for 8.8.8.8 will be sent to this mac address, and go nowhere.

Now you can intercept the packet, do your modification, but also modify the destination MAC to be your router MAC so that it goes out correctly.  Reply packets will automatically go to the server.

Comment: Well, thanks @Paul, but I only want to block the SYN-ACK from OS with src port 8000. Rest of the traffic from/to 8.8.8.8 should be handled by the OS.

Comment: Additionally, the packet I received in pcap also gets dest. mac of 11:22:33:44:55:66. I can change the dst. mac through pcap, but probably it will be nice to have a cleaner solution. :-)

Comment: It is intended that you get the MAC like that - that was the last line of my answer.  If you can intercept one packet, you can intercept them all, and just update the DST mac for them.  You aren't going to be able to stop the syn-ack coming out of the server, so you need to control the traffic flow entirely.

Comment: aah! I think I can get started with this, and if I find something better down the line - I will post it here. Thanks for your help! --IamGroot